# How do I draw an NSTextField background effect that looks like the Finder's file name label?

Tags: cocoa

How do I draw an `NSTextField` background effect that looks like the Finder's file name label?

[image: effect]

Answer (score 0):

I am implementing something like that at the moment...
In my situation I don't have to make it exactly the same, so I took the bounding text rectangle.

The best guess is that Finder takes line by line and constructs the NSBezierPath with round corners.

Answer (score 0):

I returned to this problem right now and made something very identical to Finder labels.
The main idea is to:

1. split the NSString into 2 parts: first line (that fits the rect) and all the tail (other part of string).
2. calculate the width and height of both line's rectangles (bounding)
3. create a NSBezierPath from point to point with lines and curves, going around the perimeter for both rectangles
4. consider the situations where first line has bigger/smaller width than the secondline.